# Can I use displaytag pagination with bootstrap table class

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, displaytag

I have a spring application which displays data in pagenation format using displaytag library. I want to add bootstrap table css to it .is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes found the answer.

```
<display:table export="true"  name="qd.quotelist" requestURI="/dashboard" pagesize="5" class="table table-striped">
```